# Consolidating panda dataframes: Choose the smaller absolute value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, absolute-value

I have two panda DataFrames:

Dataframe A:

```
date        ticker  return
2017-01-03  CRM     0.018040121229614625
2017-01-03  MSFT    -0.0033444816053511683
2017-01-04  CRM     0.024198086662915008
2017-01-04  MSFT    -0.0028809218950064386
2017-01-05  CRM     -0.0002746875429199269
2017-01-05  MSFT    0.0017687731146487362
```

Dataframe B:

```
date        ticker  return
2017-01-03  CRM     0.018040120991250852
2017-01-03  MSFT    -0.003344466975803595
2017-01-04  CRM     0.024198103213211475
2017-01-04  MSFT    -0.0028809268004892363
2017-01-05  CRM     -0.00027464144673694513
2017-01-05  MSFT    0.0017687829680113065
```

Now I need a third 'consolidated' dataframe:

- Same column names
- For each row I have to choose the 'return' data from DataframeA or DataframeB with the smaller absolute value

Any suggestions?

Comment: [please don't put images of code or data in the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), instead post them as text so people can reproduce your question

Comment: I have just correct that

Comment: thanks , `(pd.concat((A,B),ignore_index=True).groupby(['date','ticker'])['return']
.apply(lambda x: x.abs().min()).reset_index())`?

Comment: Almost. You are filling the new panda with the abs value. That's not what I need. I need fill it with dataframeA or dataframeB 'return' column with the smaller absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `concat+groupby` on `return` and return the `min` with `key=abs` :

```
(pd.concat((A,B),ignore_index=True)
   .groupby(['date','ticker'])['return'].min(key=abs).reset_index())
```

---

```
         date ticker    return
0  2017-01-03    CRM  0.018040
1  2017-01-03   MSFT -0.003344
2  2017-01-04    CRM  0.024198
3  2017-01-04   MSFT -0.002881
4  2017-01-05    CRM -0.000275
5  2017-01-05   MSFT  0.001769
```

Comment: If I would have a second column, Do I have to repeat the operation for each column? Or it can be done in the same line?

Answer (score 2):

**This is Edited New Answer With Runable Code**

The following code will work even if number of rows are not equal. It will first take common rows on both dataframes and then finds the correct value for required column

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## creating dummy data to get runable code
## ---------------------------------------
n_rows = 20
sub_categories = np.random.choice(4, size=n_rows)
dic1 = {
    "a": list(range(n_rows)),
    "b": sub_categories,
    "c": np.random.randn(n_rows)
}

dic2 = {
    "a": range(n_rows),
    "b": sub_categories,
    "c": np.random.randn(n_rows)
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df1.drop(index=list(np.random.choice(n_rows, 5, replace=False)), inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
df2.drop(index=list(np.random.choice(n_rows, 3, replace=False)), inplace=True)




## Main Answer
## ---------------------------------------------------------


## merge df1 and df2 then create new column c based which take min(abs(c_1, c_2))

result = df1.merge(df2, how="inner", on=["a","b"], suffixes=["_1", "_2"]).copy()
result["c"] = result["c_1"].where(np.abs(result["c_1"])<np.abs(result["c_2"]), 
                                   result["c_2"], axis=0)
display(result)

## finally reindex to remove extra columns
result = result.reindex(columns=["a","b","c"])
result
```

**Old Answer**

you can do something like below

```py
series = df1["return"].where(np.abs(df1["return"])<np.abs(df2["return"]), df2["return"], axis=0)
series
```

it will return series whose value in a row is taken from df1 if absolute value of return is less than same row in df2 else it will take value from df2

then you can replace column of either df1 or df2 or their copy to get dataframe you want

```
df1["return"] = series
```

Comment: You can do `df1["return"]=np.where(np.abs(df1["return"])<np.abs(df2["return"]), df2["return"], df1["return"])` . This will directly assign series to column in dataframe.

Comment: ya thats right, I just broke that in two steps for clarity

Comment: It is working if I have the same number of rows in dataframeA and dataframeB. How to get it If I would have some rows in dataframeA that not exists in dataframeB? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2132478 Plz check edited answer above, now it should work  even with different number of rows, :) don&#39;t forget to mark resolved if it works

Answer (score 1):

you can use `concat` to join both `dataframe`, then group by `ticker` using `groupby` and get the minimum of each group:

```
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('ticker').min().reset_index()
```

Comment: You have to include date also in groupby. Also, OP wants absolute minimum.